# Using a mix of Activities and Fragments in my application

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm building an app with a navigation drawer, and an action bar with a button which pressed should take users to a log in page. The log in page is an activity.

I have inserted what I believe to be the appropriate code, however the section in bold comes back with the following error: Annotations are not allowed here

This code previously worked, and now it has this error and my app obviously wont launch. Does anyone know why? Thanks!

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_LoginPage) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome to the Employee Log-in Page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_LoginPage:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginPageMain.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

**@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//      Code for Nav Bar Item Clicks (Button Clicks)
    int id = item.getItemId();**
```

Comment: If the code you posted here is exactly like your problem code, then please count your curly brackets